# "error: src refspec TstBranch does not match any."

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Уважаемые господа, есть проблема с коммитом в гит (конкретно - в гитлаб)

Смотрите, что я хочу сделать:

Есть проект, я делаю себе локальную копию  (`git clone`)

Затем, я хочу внести изменения и закоммитить и запушить их, но не в `master`, а в новый `branch`.

Когда я вношу изменения - всё хорошо. когда я пытаюсь сделать `push` - я получаю ошибку. Это - краткая версия.

Вот подробности:

1) делаю `git clone`

2) вношу изменения

3) через WEB-интерфейс гитлаба делаю новый бранч. Называется `TstBranch`

4) делаю `git commit -m "Что я сделал - подробный комментарий"`

5) проверяю `git status` - красота! можно грамоту давать. все файлы есть и все на своих местах. Именно этот набор файлов я хочу протолкнуть на сервер.

6) делаю `git push -u origin TstBranch`

получаю ошибку

```
c:\Projects\TradingG0_Solution>git push -u origin TstBranch

error: src refspec TstBranch does not match any.

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://tst@GitLab0.junecat.ru/konst/TradingG0_Solution.git'
```

Для надежности я прилагаю два скриншота, на которых видны все эти команды, которые я выполнял и их результаты.

Как бы мне сделать все таки commit и push в нужную ветку?
[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по вашим скриншотам и по вашим словам вы всё время работаете в ветке `master`, вам нужно было создать новую ветку (что вы и сделали), перейти на неё(что не сделали), через `git` консоль к примеру это делается так:

```
git checkout -b TstBranch
```

И тогда будучи уже на этой ветке делать изменения и выливать их, а так получается вы всё это время пытались вылить `master` думаючи что это другая ветка.

Чтобы такое не повторялось проверяйте текущую ветку командой:

```
git status
```

Переходить между ветками командой:

```
git checkout name
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ответ мне помог, научился пеерключаться между ветками!
Важно было также увидеть, куда смотреть в вывод команды git status, чтобы видеть текущую ветку.

Comment: @S.H. советую поставить Smartgit или SourceTree или аналоги, я использую 1 вариант, удобней как по мне. Хотя на сервере приходится так же руками всё делать

Comment: Спасибо, 
моя работа по большей части происходит в Visual Studio (2015), и я перешел к командной строке чтобы лучше понять Git и GitLab.
Потом вернусь в графическую среду, когда буду понимать, что просиходит, и буду делать коммиты однйо кнопкой - "по накатанному пути".
Проблема, с которой я сейчас столкнулся - странная:
GitLab я настраивал сам, по руководству с сайта GitLab'а.
И там для доступа к проектам может использоватьсмя один из двух протоколов: родной git или https.
Так вот, по HTTPS всё работает. А по протоколу Git я получаю ошибку "Permission denied, please try again"

Comment: @S.H. тоже была такая проблема когда настраивал его, не помню как решил, по моему порты открывал, но на самом деле пользуемся https и никаких проблем не было

Comment: А можно уточнить: когда ты открыл порты (скорее всего, понадобится только порт 22) - то проблема решилась? проверить просто: попробуй склонировать проект по git - протоколу из всоего gitLab.
Я написал подробный вопрос с картнками на эту тему:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679220/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-gitlab-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83-git-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-permission-denied-pl